# How can I fix pvc floor damage like this?

Tags: floor, pvc

How can I fix old pvc floor damage like the one in this picture ?

[image]

Comment: Putting a carpet or something over that section will be the easiest.  Those floors are not really up to being repaired, once the surface is damaged.  Replacement of those pieces is really the only repair/fix, unless you can put up with some wood putty/paint there.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:  [LVT repair kit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00O4CWC9W)

I have used this kit with good results. It's a bit of an art, but worth the time and better than ripping up the floor.